# Отправка ajax запроса при изменении состояния чекбокса

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть таблица (генерится джаваскриптом) вида:

```
row = $('<tr class="paid">');
row.append($('<td>').text(i + 1));
```

...

```
row.append($('<td>').html('<input value="' + type + '" type="checkbox" checked id="' + dog.number + '">'));
```

как отправить ajax при изменении состояния чекбокса?
сама функция отправки трудностей не вызывает. со статическим элементом не сложно (addEventListener), но как написать слушатель для динамического элемента никак не допру.

Comment: Во-первых, если вы указали в тегах jquery, и в коде у вас явно его использование, то зачем писать о addEventListener, стоит тогда уж говорить о чем-то таком `$("#countries input:checkbox").change(function() {});` Во-вторых, если у вас контент формируется динамически, то стоит либо банально дождаться его формирования и после навесить событие точно также, как для статического, либо навешивать событие(я) в момент формирования кода. Почитайте про асинхронность, в общем, и этапы срабатывания того или иного кода, начать можно с функции jquery.ready() - она тут не слишком в тему, по поймете принцип

Answer (score 3):

Можно навешать на элемент событие на этапе создания:

```js
let input = $('<input value="1" type="checkbox" checked id="check_id">');
input.on('change', function(){
  console.log(this.checked);
})
$('body').append(input);
```

```css
body{padding-bottom: 152px;}/*Из-за консоли*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Также можно воспользоваться делегированием события:

```js
// Сгенерируем несколько строк
for (let i = 1; i<=10; i++) {
  let row = $('<tr><td>');
  let input = $('<input type="checkbox">');
  input.val(i);
  row.append(input);
  row.append('<span>'+ i + '</span>');
  $('#table').append(row);
}


$('#table').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function(){
  console.log(this.value, this.checked);
})
```

```css
body{padding-bottom: 152px;}/*Из-за консоли*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table"></table>
```

[Документация .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 3):

Не круто навешивать обработчик на каждый создаваемый чекбокс, поэтому разумно делегировать обработку события change на родительский контейнер. В данном случае на таблицу.

```
$('table').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function(){
    var dataObj = {
        id: this.id,
        value: this.value
    }
    $.ajax({
        data: dataObj,
        url: 'some.php',
        success: function(data){
            console.log('Сервер вернул:' + data);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
row.append($('<td>').html('<input value="' + type + '" type="checkbox" checked id="' + 
  dog.number + '" class="ajaxcheckbox">'));

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("table").on("click", ".ajaxcheckbox", function(e) {
    $.ajax({
      data: { 
        id: this.id,
        value: this.value
      },
      ...
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: проверил - не работает

Comment: @abakan ну не работает, так не работает. Что ж тут поделаешь? Значит, я, вредитель, дал Вам неработающий код.

Comment: да ладно, чего уж там. вы дали направление копания, это не менее важно. а по поводу кода - может у меня что-то не так, просто с полпинка не заработало ))

Answer (score 2):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var i = 0;
  
  $('#add').click(function() {
    var row = $('<tr class="paid">');
    i++;
    row.append($('<td>').text(i));
    var check = $('<input type="checkbox" checked id="' + i + '">');
    row.append($('<td>').append(check));
    $('#data').append(row);
    check.click(function(){
      console.log(this.id);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="data"></table>
<button id="add">Add</button>
```

Comment: Только выводиться вот всегда `3` будет, так как на тот момент она уже проитериуется до конца :)

Comment: @Станислав Вы правы. Думал об одном, а писал другое. Конечно же там должно быть `this.id`